# declare printf function by myself (using Vistual Studio 2012 and c++)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I want to declare printf function by myself, and try if the code can work.
I looked into the `<stdio.h>` and found it declared as:

```
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl printf(_In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format, ...);
```

Then I found
`_Check_return_opt_`  defined in `<crtdefs.h>`
`_CRTIMP` defined in `<crtdefs.h>`
`_In_z_ _Printf_format_string_` defined in `<sal.h>`

So my code is as:

```
#include <crtdefs.h>
#include <sal.h>
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl printf(_In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format, ...);
int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

I guess this will work, but it gets an error:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...
What's wrong with my code? Are there anything I missed in `<stdio.h>`?

I have already read a question on stackoverflow.
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155631/microsoft-visual-studio-2012-version-of-printf-function-declaration)
It helps, but doesn't solve my problem.

I also learn to know that an `extern "C"` function works fine. such as:

```
extern "C" int printf (const char * __format, ...);
```

But I think this still not accounts for my doubt.

Comment: Why are you doing this? There is no guarantee that whatever you come up with will work in Visual Studio 2013 or any future version.

Comment: Use the `printf` that the compiler has determined is the right one.  The one that is correct is found in `stdio.h` or `<cstdio>`.  But why do this?  It seems that so many want to actively cause problems when no problem needs to exist.  Just include the correct header.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Just curious about it, and try to find if my comprehension of something is right.(Maybe about my comprehension of compiling, I think. I have not learned about compiling, but I get some tips form people around me.)You are right, this should not be used for coding, just an experiment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Thank you for you advice. I won't use this in my code. I am just curious about how something functions in c++ or VS2012.

Comment: The practical answer is "Just `#include <cstdio>`." This web site prefers practical solutions to real problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `stdio.h`, was the prototype for `printf` inside an `extern "C" {}` block?  Note that this block could be large and so you might not have noticed it.  If so, you need to use `extern "C"` around your prototype.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote, otherwise I will vote. But then I find I can accept, (*^__^*) 。

Answer (score 0):

The `extern "C"` should remove your doubt - without that you are compiling the declaration as C++ which doesn't use a linking convention that's the same as C (which is how `printf()` is compiled in the library).

You can fix the problem using `extern "C"` or compiling your program as a C program instead of C++ (change the name of the source file to have a `.c`extension).

Comment: It is really about the extern "C".I have missed the extern "C" {} in <stdio.h>.